# Combine CSS Attribute Selectors

Tags: html, css

is there a way to combine CSS2 Attribute Selectors like `tr[id^="foo" AND id$="bar"]`, so it selects all `<tr id="foo_something_bar">` **but not** `<tr id="foo_something">` or `<tr id="something_bar">`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The same way you combine any selectors.

```
tr[id^="foo"][id$="bar"]
```

Those two substring matching selectors, however, are being introduced in the CSS 3 draft. They are not CSS 2.

Comment: If you have a new question, you can [ask it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).