# jQuery selector of type 'input' excluding some matched elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've following `HTML`,

```
 <input type=text id='input_field_1` class='row'/>
 <input type=text id='input_field_2` class='row'/>
 <input type=text id='optional_field_3` class='row'/>
```

In above `DOM` if I want to select the elements who's `id` starts with `input_field_` then I'm able to achieve this by `$("input[id^='input_field_']")`

Now some more `input` elements are added to existing `DOM` structure,those are

```
 <input type=text id='input_field_min_4` class='row'/>
 <input type=text id='input_field_max_5` class='row'/>
 <input type=text id='optional_field_6` class='row'/>
```

If I use `$("input[id^='input_field_']")` then all the elements starting with `input_field_`, including `input_field_min_4` and `input_field_max_5` are also selecting.

I don't want this, I want to exclude `input_field_min_4` and `input_field_max_5`,for that if do some like `$("input[id^='input_field_'],input:not[id^='input_field_m']")` then result is not getting what I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector you have is invalid and will cause a JavaScript error. It is missing parenthesis around the `:not`.

```
console.log($("input[id^='input_field_'],input:not([id^='input_field_m'])"));
                                                  ^                     ^
```

However, even if they are added, the presence of the `,` between the selectors results in selecting `id="^input_field_"` **or** not `id="^input_field_m"`, which actually matches all of the inputs.

You need to combine attribute selectors ([Combine CSS Attribute Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942286/combine-css-attribute-selectors)) and the negation pseudo class [`:not`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation) together, so the following will select the first two `<input>` elements.

```
console.log($('input[id^="input_field_"]:not([id^="input_field_m"])'));
```

Also the HTML code in question uses some inconsistent quotes. The backtick might be causing some issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not` method:

```
$("input[id^='input_field_']").not('[id*=min], [id*=max]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A5Gn8/

Note that these selectors are not efficient. You should consider using different logic for selecting elements, *if this is possible*.

A faster option:

```
$("input").filter(function(){
   return this.id.match(/^input_field_\d/);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ueeht/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$("input[id^='input_field_']").not("[id^='input_field_m']");
```

Still think, though, that you'd better use additional attributes (like `role`, for example, or `data` ones) to make this distinction AND simplify your selector. If, for example, tbese additional inputs are marked with something like `data-limit="min"`, `data-limit="max"`, your selector will be as trivial as...

```
$("input[id^='input_field_']").not("[data-limit]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Separating selector with comma makes `or` condition and you need `and` here, you have to combine the condition and exclude the id using `:not`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VH9aD/)**

```
$("input[id^=input_field_]:not([id^=input_field_m])");
```