# Trying to combines two CSS Attributes

Tags: css

I am trying to merge:

```
span[itemprop='description']
{
 color:#8395a7;
 font-size:smaller;
}
```

And

```
span[itemprop='streetAddress']
{
 color:#8395a7;
 font-size:smaller;
}
```

This question has been asked before here [but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942286/combine-css-attribute-selectors) it didn't work for me. I tried this and it failed:

```
span[itemprop='description'][itemprop='streetAddress']
{
 color:#8395a7;
 font-size:smaller;
}
```

Any idea how to merge these?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine CSS Attribute Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942286/combine-css-attribute-selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```css
span[itemprop='description'], span[itemprop='streetAddress']
{
 color:#8395a7;
 font-size:smaller;
}
```

```html
<span itemprop="description">I am description.</span>
<span itemprop="streetAddress">I am address.</span>
```